# Java script only reads 7 rows of data from log file

Tags: javascript, php

For some reason my script will only read upto 7 rows of data from the log file. Of course I need it to read unlimited (within reason) rows of data because my log file will have at least 1000 - 2000 rows of data every 30 minutes to 1 hour. I can't figure out why if there is more than 7 rows of data the script just seems to not run at all.

Here is the code to get the data:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Send Data Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body onload="clickFunction()">
     <div id="result"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

                function clickFunction() {
                    var sURL = "dump.log";
                    var oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    oRequest.open("GET", sURL, false);
                    oRequest.send(null)

                    if (oRequest.status == 200) {//code 200 is successful case
                       debugger;
                        var fileContent = oRequest.responseText;

                        var jsonArray = new Array();
                        while (fileContent.indexOf("]") > 0) {
                            var jsonStr = fileContent.substring(fileContent.indexOf("[") + 1, fileContent.indexOf("]"));
                            fileContent = fileContent.substring(fileContent.indexOf("]") + 1);
                            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
                            jsonArray.push(jsonObj);
                        }
                       debugger;
                        for (i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
                            var jsonStr1 = jsonArray[i];
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "newText.php",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: {
                                    email: jsonStr1.email,
                                    event: jsonStr1.event,
                                    timestamp: jsonStr1.timestamp,
                                    sg_message_id: jsonStr1.sg_message_id
                                }
                                ,
                                dataType: "JSON",
                                success: function (data) {
                                   // debugger;
                                    alert(data);

                                 $("#result").html(data);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Error executing XMLHttpRequest call!");
                    }
            };
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code used to store it in my database (file name newText.php)

```
<?php
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($_REQUEST); die;
    $email = json_encode($_POST["email"]);
    $timestamp = json_encode($_POST["timestamp"]);        
    $event = json_encode($_POST["event"]); 
    $sg_message_id = json_encode($_POST["sg_message_id"]);

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$queryRes = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO sendgrid_data (email,event,sg_message_id,post_time) VALUES ('$email','$event','$sg_message_id','$timestamp')");

mysqli_close($con);

if($queryRes>0){
    echo 'Worked'; // so I know it worked
}


?>
```

UPDATE:

So I found the problem. Some rows of data start with  [   and end with   ]  but other rows start with   [    then end that row with    }   and on the next row start with   {   then on that row end with    ]

It's a way that I get data when it's about the same person. So how can I make the script pick out rows of data when some are different?

Comment: Is there anything unique about the 7th row of these files?  The 8th?

Comment: Nothing at all. It's all the same type of data.

Comment: Any errors in the web inspector console?

Comment: @RandyThomas your JS script consists of two parts: 1 - filling `jsonArray` with data, 2 - sending the data to the PHP script. At which part the problem occurs? Have you tried to place `console.log(jsonArray);` after filling it? My advice is to put `console.log` calls at every meaningful place in the code and trace what happens.

Comment: I found the problem just don't know how to fix it. It seems that some rows don't end with ] the end with } because they continue on to the next row and that row ends with ]. That's where the script hangs. Any ideas on how to change the code so that on those lines it will read both rows separate and not hang?